# Vuetify v-flex offset-*(1-12) not working properly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using Vuetify 1.5.0 at time of writing this. But when ever I am trying to use offset for any breakpoint on v-flex, its adding offset on that breakpoint and up for Example in this case it is adding offset on **md and up** as well . Below is my code. Please what am i doing wrong here and how can correct this.

```
 <v-container class="teal">
    <v-layout row wrap class="red">  
      <v-flex sm12 md8 lg7 offset-md2 class="blue">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex sm12 md8 lg5 offset-md2 class="orange">
         <h1>Hello Hi</h1>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
 </v-container>
```

And is the screenshot taken on **lg** screen.

[image]

as you can see, its wrapping column in new line even though it should not.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

The `offset-md2` being applied on **md and up** is expected behaviour if you don't specify any "upper" offset (like `offset-lg*`). Likewise when you specify `sm8` (for small) and don't specify any `md*` or `lg*`, the `sm8` would be applied for **sm and up**.

If you want to ignore the offsets on a large screen, you could use `offset-lg0`, like so:

```
<v-container class="teal">
    <v-layout row wrap class="red">  
      <v-flex sm12 md8 lg7 offset-md2 offset-lg0 class="blue">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex sm12 md8 lg5 offset-md2 offset-lg0 class="orange">
         <h1>Hello Hi</h1>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
 </v-container>
```